# How is the ground state energy of the helium atom experimentally determined?

Tags: experimental-physics, atomic-physics, physical-chemistry

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helium_atom) the ground state energy of the helium atom is −78.95 eV. From the little I understood of spectroscopy, I believe that allows us to measure the differences in energies between orbitals; so how can we actually measure the ground state energy?

Answer (score 1):

So you measure the energy difference between the ground state of Helium and the state where the Helium nucleus and the two electrons are at large distances from each other.

Answer (score 0):

One measures the first ionization potential (24.59 eV). The second ionization potential can also be measured but it is just 4 Ry = 54.42 eV. The sum comes out a little bit too large but I should have corrected for the finite mass of the alpha particle.

Comment: Can you elaborate? I do not understand your answer or how it answers the question I asked.

Comment: The binding is the energy to take the atom apart. First you take one electron off, that takes 24.6 eV. Then you take the second one off from He$^+$, costs four times as much as taking the electron from hydrogen, 4 Ry = 54.4 eV. Sum 79.0 eV. I don't know how to elaborate more.